# C# SqlDataReader for int

Tags: c#, integer, int, sqldatareader

I am confused by the following issue;

I am trying to retrieve a record (column 'EmployeeId' (int)) using a SqlDataReader.

When I run the query directly on the server, I got the record correctly. When I run the same procedure to get another column (string) I got the record correctly.

I assume the **issue is due to the fact that I try to get an int**, the program skips the

```
while (mySqlDbDataReader.Read())
```

and goes directly to

```
catch (Exception eMsg1)
            {
```

Here is the full procedure

```
public string getUserId()
{
    //Check user details against login in Db
    //Local variables to capture values from Db
    string varId = "";

    //Connection string
    conn = sqlDbConnection.GetConnection();
    SqlCommand newCmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    newCmd.Connection = conn;
    newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    //Query
    userCredentials connectedUser = new userCredentials();
    newCmd.CommandText = "SELECT EmployeeId FROM tblEmployees WHERE WinLogin='" + connectedUser.getWindowsLogin() + "';";

    //Connect
    newCmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();

    //Utilisation du try-catch permettant de fermer la connexion même en cas de plantage
    try
    {
        SqlDataReader mySqlDbDataReader = newCmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (mySqlDbDataReader.Read())
        {
            //Tester que le résultat n’est pas NULL afin d’éviter un plantage au moment du crash
            if (mySqlDbDataReader["EmployeeId"] != System.DBNull.Value)
            {
                //Récupérer le nom à l’aide d’un cast
                varId = (string)mySqlDbDataReader["EmployeeId"];                        
            }
            else
            {
                varId = "Unknown";                       
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception eMsg1)
    {
        //In the event of trouble, display error msg
        //MessageBox.Show("Error while executing query: " + eMsg1.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(eMsg1);

        //Control
        MessageBox.Show("Empty");
    }
    finally
    {
        //Close DB connection
        conn.Close();
    }

    return varId;
}`
```

Thanks for your help!

Brice

Comment: Well if it's hitting the catch block, it's getting an exception, so what is the exception that it is raising?

Comment: FYI. You have a risky SQL injection opportunity in your code.  You should strongly consider reading about SQL injection attacks and how to avoid them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am trying to retrieve a record (column 'EmployeeId' (int)) using a SqlDataReader.

So why are you casting to a string?

```
varId = (string)mySqlDbDataReader["EmployeeId"];
```

That's the problem. You should be casting it to an `int` instead, or using `GetInt32`:

```
// You don't need a local variable for this at all...
return mySqlDbDataReader.GetInt32(0);
```

(Here the 0 is "the ordinal of the `EmployeeId` column; you can use `GetOrdinal` to get the ordinal for a named column.)

You'll need to change your method's return type to `int` as well, of course - or call `ToString` if you *really* want the value as a string. (I'd strongly advise against it though.)

You should be able to see the details when you write the exception out to the console. I don't think execution is skipping the `Read` call at all - it's reading the result, then failing to convert the `int` to a `string`, causing an exception to be thrown.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick response ;)

Comment: You cannot pass column name in `GetInt32(...)` method. It only accepts `The zero-based column ordinal`.

Comment: @AnimalsAreNotOursToEat: Yup, I always forget that. Will edit.

Answer (score 1):

You are casting an `int` to a `string`, which you cannot do.

```
// Change varId to an int and cast to an int
varId = (int)mySqlDbDataReader["EmployeeId"];
```

Or

```
// Call ToString to get the string representation of the underlying value
varId = mySqlDbDataReader["EmployeeId"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Both Jons are correct. It is just that casting that appears to be raising the problem. I'd like to suggest using a Typed `QueryTableAdapter` for your purpose. Simply add a new `DataSet` to your project, right-click in the DataSet Designer and add a Query. Type your query there, introduce your variable (user name in this case I guess) and it will generate a query function in your QueryAdapter that will accept the variable from you, run the query and return EmployeeID. Moreover it will also save you from SQL injection type of things because it uses typed parameters internally.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the int:

instead of

```
//Récupérer le nom à l’aide d’un cast
varId = (string)mySqlDbDataReader["EmployeeId"];
```

use

```
//Récupérer le nom à l’aide d’un cast
varId = mySqlDbDataReader["EmployeeId"].ToString();
```

This is of course assuming that `EmployeeId` is not nullable.

Comment: What's the difference between the two?

Comment: Hah!  Copy and paste got me!